# How to move older files to new location?

Tags: perl, batch-file

Recently I try to write script to move older files(including folders) (2 years/ 730 days) to another location(From C: to D:) due to storage capacity is limited.

At 1st, I think I can use `XCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY` and I tried it, but end up I realize these two commands is only COPY but not move that's why it named with copy.

Maybe I can write this in perl script? or any batch command that can help me on this? Any related post/information/suggestion/script to share? Thank you!

Comment: How about the `move` command. `Move /?`

Comment: Can't you delete the copied files?

Comment: @Monacraft Let me take a look on it. Thanks!

Comment: @npocmaka I think of it, but when copy files it might failed and then perform delete might cause the files to lost. If do checking before delete it. Then it take another extra step for it. If so, I think `Move` is better than this solution.

Comment: you can use conditional execution or to check the %errorlevel%

Comment: @npocmaka hmm, that's new for me.. thanks for the suggestion.. let me take a look on it. But still it take another step to delete =P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
robocopy c:\source d:\target /minage:730 /e /move
```

Copy from source to target files with a minimum age of 730 days, including subfolders and once copied, remove from source.

Comment: hmm, it also delete off my `C:\source` if the folder is older than 730 days. Is a problem to me.. I can't delete off my folders because there's might new files inside the folder. I only can delete the files.

Comment: @thor_that_new_in_programming, change `/MOVE` to `/MOV`